# Annoying Trend - Stylesheets on Alternate Domain - Firefox Problems

Tags: css, firefox, dns

Is it just me or does a site like:
http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/04/fubu-mvc

often load without a style, because the author put the stylesheet over on:
http://cdn1.infoq.com/styles/style.css

I know this is all trendy way to do css, image and javascript files now. But I seem to bump into this issue all the time. Is it only a Firefox issue?

Comment: Or is it a "any browser on windows" issue? Seems like it could be related to when the OS is trying to resolve the DNS name it hasn't encountered recently.

Comment: Mostly a problem on the server, I am 100% sure its not the browser's fault.

Comment: It happens when using Firefox on Twitter all the time too. I always check now... and I have never seen Firefox screw this up when the css file is coming from the exact same domain.

Answer (score 1):

I just saved the source locally and tested it out. It seems that when the styles do not appear, the LINK element is resolving as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://cdn3.infoq.com/styles/style.css;jsessionid=2BAD2D184D56C3163ADC70B99E711F47" />
```

..the important part being the ';jsessionid....' which is knocking the css out of commission.

On a reload, that jsessionid apparently kicks into action for some reason, and the LINK element resolves normally as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://cdn4.infoq.com/styles/style.css" />
```

I'm not sure what is actually causing the jsessionid to not work, then work on reload...but that seems to be the culprit in one way or another. Also, I had the same exact experience in IE7 and Safari...so definitely not a browser specific thing.

Comment: I'd suspect the url with ;jssessionid is looking for the physical file with the appended jssessionid stuff which don't exist. might work better if it were ?jssessionid

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is because firefox checks for crossdomain.xml to see if the request is allowed, and IE just grabs it regardless.

Comment: Firefox looks from crossdomain.xml to get CSS files?

Comment: I'm not sure, but that seems like a possible cause. You'd have to do more research about it yourself.

Comment: Looks like crossdomain.xml only relevant to XHR requests from the initial searches I have done.